# Selenium Tests running locally but failing on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: selenium, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm kind new to the DevOps world, and I'm having an issue where my test team can run their tests locally however some of them are failing when using a Pipeline.

The tests that are failing are upload files ones, however this only happens on a specific webpage of our solution.

Any idea of what can be happening?

Pipeline Steps:
We are using an Azure Agent (windows 2019)

1 - We install Google chrome webdrive (its then configured on the code)

2 - We run the following Maven script

```
  mvn clean verify -P $(MavenProfiles) -e -Dcucumber.options="--tags $(Tags)" - 
  Dheadless=$(headless) -Denv=$(Environment) -Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/log4j2.xml
```

This is the error the the test throws:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebElement 'By.cssSelector: *[id*='Client_Name']' was not found on page. Exception: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for ui.controllers.GlobalUtilities$1@29a33620 (tried for 16 second(s) with 2000 milliseconds interval)

I noticed this error all through the pipeline logs, however only fail on specific tests.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more information about the error you are getting and some code of the tests you are running, so someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Marco Carvalho; from experience, the most likely thing is that the element is genuinely not present on the page. This might be because the page failed to load at all, or it loaded in an unexpected state without the control showing.

Comment: A screenshot would most likely tell you straight away what the problem is; can your test runner do that?

Comment: @VinceBowdren thank you for your response.
This error does seem to persist all throughout the run, and other like - Exception: org. Openqa. Selenium. StaleElementReferenceException - also seem to be presented, however, in this case I think the code tries multiple times until the web element is ready.